Duplicate Ecoinvent database in Brightway2.5
I want to duplicate the entire ecoinvent database in my brightway2.5 program, how can I do this? not just copy one activity, but copy the entire ecoinvent database -> all activities at once

Please look at the documentation before coming here:
https://docs.brightway.dev/en/latest/content/cheatsheet/databases.html
It is clearly explained here:
copied_database = bd.Database('<database_name>').copy('<new_name>')

i always get the error message "OperationalError: database table is locked" when I run this code, (bd.Database('<database_name>').copy('<new_name>')) could you please help me?
